# Is the Senran Kagura Anime/OVA related to the games plot wise?

Tags: senran-kagura

So looking in my emails i noticed that there was a *Senran Kagura* Anime and a search on [AniDB.net](http://anidb.net/perl-bin/animedb.pl?adb.search=Senran%20Kagura&show=animelist&do.search=search) shows there is also an OVA.

I have *Senran Kagura Shinovi Versus Let's Get Physical* on the Vita and plan to get *Senran Kagura Burst* on the 3DS so i am wondering if the Anime and OVA of *Senran Kagura* are related to games plot wise?